# Design mode or sys.all_columns, why are nvarchar lengths different?

Tags: sql

When I need to view a table's schema, I use `sp_help`, which will give me something like:

```
Column Name Type     Length
My_COLUMN   nvarchar 50
```

But if I open up the table in Design Mode, I'll get

```
MY_COLUMN nvarchar(25)
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

25 is the maximum length in characters.

50 is the maximum length in bytes.

`n[var]char` columns consume 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score 2):

The "length" you're seeing in the `sp_help` listing is the length in bytes and, since nvarchar is a double-byte data type, it is double what was declared in the table creation.